How to simplify all of words formatting, remove styles
I’m trying to strip all styles from a document while continuing to preserve the look. So instead of style 2 having italics being applied to a sentence, I want it style 1, with italics.
“Wait this is dumb let me explain why you don’t need to-“
No. The software I’m importing the document into needs things formatted like this. It can’t recognize styles. It can recognize bolds and italics.
Why? Because &;):$/ me that’s why.
So far I’ve been hunting down the various styles, selecting it, selecting “select all text that shares a style”, then stripping formatting then reapplying. This works when things are normal, no edge cases.
It’s the edge cases that are doing me in. An italic style with words in the middle that are non-italic (because someone who had the file before me did manual changes) will mess with this. Word will - gods knows why - select both the italic and the non-italic. Then when I strip styles and apply italics, it’ll apply italics to ALL the text, not just the original.
So we’ve been manually going over and making things right, and it’s driving us insane. The files are hundreds of thousands of words (book manuscripts), and it’s all simple logic. There HAS to be an easier way to “deformat” the text. There should be a simple way of looking at a word, and saying “this is a normal word, a bold word, or an italic word”, and making the markdown reflect it.
Putting it into a semi technical way as I understand it: word is applying classes to my text. I don’t want classes. I just want text with the simple bold/italic/nothing markdown.
I’m very open to using VBA for this. It just feels like there should be a simple solution. I’ve searched through a few other threads, but there was a lot of “lol no”, “go copy paste it to notepad and paste back”, and a “let me explain why this isn’t something you want to do”.
This is something I want to do… although I am open to copy pasting to notepad++ or something if that would work.
